# Delay on Google Cloud push-to-deploy?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying google cloud for my PHP site. I use bitbucket git repo and connected it to my google cloud account. Now I want to test the push-to-deploy feature. I set the release pipeline so that any git push to the bitbucket repo supposed to be deployed automatically to the compute engine. But it just won't get deployed at all. Google doesn't show anything on the commit table in the release pipeline page, although we could see that the code is successfully updated via Browse menu.
[image]

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I tried deleting the old pipeline and creating a new one, then I push to my bitbucket repository, the changes show up on the cloud repository but the release pipeline never triggers.

Answer (score 1):

The Google little changed the feature of push to deploy. Now you have to create the Jenkins Instance to build and test your application. Go through the docs [1] and follow the steps.

[1] Pushto deploy: https://cloud.google.com/tools/repo/push-to-deploy